# Node js Passport js store ID to a variable when the user submit the sign up page

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js

I'm creating an application to practice for my self. so now i need to store the ID when new user submitting the form. So if you anybody have an please let me know. I need this because I"m gonna create a randomly generated hash with the newly signed up user' ID. Please help me to do this

thank you

This is the code for signup for new user.

```
passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField : 'username',
    passwordField : 'password',
    passReqToCallback : true
},
function(req, username, password, done) {
    process.nextTick(function() {
        User.findOne({'email': req.body.email}, function(err, user1) {
            if (err) return done(err);
            User.findOne({'local.username': username}, function(err, user2){
                if (err) return done(err);
                if (user1) {
                    return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'That email is already exist.'));
                }
                if (user2) {
                    return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'That username is already exist.'));
                }
                else {
                    var newUser = new User();
                    newUser.local.username = username;
                    newUser.local.password = newUser.generateHash(password);
                    newUser.usertype = "592000f0161d63ac334358d3";
                    newUser.first = req.body.first;
                    newUser.last = req.body.last;
                    newUser.email = req.body.email;
                    newUser.save(function(err) {
                        if (err)
                            throw err;
                        return done(null, newUser);
                    });
                }
            })  
        });
    });
}));
```

Comment: attach what did you  tried

Comment: i already created a user sign up with passport and now i need to store the newly registered user's ID to a variable to create a random generated hash with the ID... So can you help me to do this

Comment: call newUser._id after calling save method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `newUser.id = req.body.id;` (sometimes `_id` is also used).